# ValueError when I compare a concrete value within an array with an integer value

Tags: python, arrays

I get the error mentioned in the title in the following code:

```py
import numpy




def solve(index):
    if (index >80):
        return sudoku


    rowIndex = int(index/9)
    columnIndex = index % 9


    if sudoku[rowIndex][columnIndex]!= 0:
        return solve(index+1)

    for input in range (1,10):
        if checking(rowIndex, columnIndex, input):
            sudoku[rowIndex][columnIndex] = input
            if solve(index + 1):

                return sudoku
            sudoku[rowIndex][columnIndex]=0

    return False






solve(start)
```

I have already looked at a few contributions to this error, and  my understanding of the error is that your get it if you compare two arrays with each other or you compare the entire array with a scalar value.
But the only if-statements where I use the array are concrete values ​​within the array for example `array[i][j] =! 0` 
And also it surprises me that the code works completely fine until the last recursion call.

Comment: I'm also surprised that it works at all. `sudoku` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: You get a lot more information about the error in the stack trace, why havent you included it?

Comment: I'm really sorry. I thought for the sake of clarity it is better if I only define the code where I think the error occurs. But if this does not allow an exact localization I insert the complete code

Comment: @Sayse Sorry, I include it also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you return either the np array or a boolean value from solve().
Try returning None instead of False.

```py
def solve(index):
    if (index >80):
        return sudoku

    rowIndex = int(index/9)
    columnIndex = index % 9

    if sudoku[rowIndex][columnIndex]!= 0:
        return solve(index+1)

    for input in range (1,10):
        if checking(rowIndex, columnIndex, input):
            sudoku[rowIndex][columnIndex] = input
            if not solve(index + 1) is None:
                return sudoku
            sudoku[rowIndex][columnIndex]=0

    return None
```

And change the if conditions to accomodate:

```py
if not solve(index + 1) is None:
```